# for loop and if statement to calculate months meeting profit citeria

Tags: r, for-loop, if-statement, countif

Simple loop issue and I know there are multiple ways to do this but for learning R I am trying to calculate the same answer multiple ways. Thanks for any help!

Problem calculate the number of months the post-tax profit is above the average for the year

## Data

```
revenue <- c(14574.49, 7606.46, 8611.41, 9175.41, 8058.65, 8105.44, 11496.28, 9766.09, 10305.32, 14379.96, 10713.97, 15433.50)
expenses <- c(12051.82, 5695.07, 12319.20, 12089.72, 8658.57, 840.20, 3285.73, 5821.12, 6976.93, 16618.61, 10054.37, 3803.96)
tax_rate <- .3

#monthly profit
profit_pre_tax <- revenue - expenses
profit_post_tax <- (revenue - expenses) * (1-tax_rate)
#Margin
profit_pre_tax_margin <- profit_pre_tax/revenue
profit_post_tax_margin <- profit_post_tax/revenue

#good and bad months
avg_profit <- mean(profit_post_tax)
all_avg_profit <- rep(avg_profit,length(profit_post_tax))
good_months <- 0
bad_months <- 0

#loop doesnt work getting an error that it only runs the if once, I also tried avg_profit but get the #same warning
for (i in 1:length(revenue)) {
  if (profit_post_tax > all_avg_profit) {
    good_months <- good_months + 1
  } else {
    bad_months <- bad_months + 1
  }
}

#code works I get the correct answer of 6
good_m <- profit_post_tax[profit_post_tax > avg_profit]
num_good_m <- length(good_m)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your `for` loop you get an error because, you are comparing the entire vector `profit_post_tax` to the entire vector `all_avg_profitall` at each iterations.

To solve this issue, you can do:

```r
for (i in 1:length(revenue)) {
  if (profit_post_tax[i] > all_avg_profit[i]) {
    good_months <- good_months + 1
  } else {
    bad_months <- bad_months + 1
  }
}
```

And you will get your answer.

**Alternative**

You can go very simpler by doing:

```r
gm <- sum(profit_post_tax > all_avg_profit)
bm <- sum(profit_post_tax <= all_avg_profit)
```

**EDIT: calculate over the average**

BTW, you don't need to do `all_avg_profit <- rep(avg_profit,length(profit_post_tax))`, you can go straight and do for your `for` loop:

```r
for (i in 1:length(revenue)) {
  if (profit_post_tax[i] > avg_profit) {
    good_months <- good_months + 1
  } else {
    bad_months <- bad_months + 1
  }
}
```

and for the `sum` example below:

```r
gm <- sum(profit_post_tax > avg_profit)
bm <- sum(profit_post_tax <= avg_profit)
```

Comment: Thanks for the help! I knew it was something simple. Also I have alternative code towards the bottom but appreciate you pointing out the other way as well.

Comment: Glad that it helps you ! ;) Your last line of code is also a good and pretty straightforward solution.  There is many ways to get the same results in R. For example, you can have a look on `sapply` function or `dplyr` package. It doesn't mean it is simpler, just different and could be relevant in particular situations.